# Found LaGrange Error is zero but graph doesn't agree

Tags: taylor-expansion

Problem:

> Find an upper bound on the error for approximating $f(1/2)$ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^{1/5}}$ using the second degree Maclaurin polynomial.

$|f^3(x)|\leq M$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$

$\frac{66}{125}|\frac{1}{(1+x)^{16/5}}|\leq M$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$

$\frac{66}{125}|\frac{1}{(1+x)^{16/5}}|$ is maximized on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ at $x=0$

Therefore, $|R_2(x)|\leq \frac{|f^3(0)|}{3!}|0-0|^3=0$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ but on desmos, this isn't true.

[image]

Comment: What theorem are you basing your "Therefore $\lvert R_2(x)\rvert\le 0$" on, specifically?

Comment: @Gae.S. taylor's inequality

Comment: @Gae.S. but the center and the $x$ I chose to find $M$ are both zero.

Comment: Yes, and in fact $T_n(0)=\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j=f(0)$.

Comment: @Gae.S. but the taylor should equal the function not just at zero but on the whole interval. It doesn't.

Comment: What? Of course it doesn't. The Taylor polynomial should satisfy $\lvert f(x)-T_n(x)\rvert\le \frac{M}{(n+1)!}\lvert x-a\rvert^{n+1}$ for all $x$ such that et cetera.

Comment: @Gae.S. So the $x$ in $|f^3(x)|$ and the $x$ in $|x-a|^{n+1}$ can be different? This is the root of my confusion. Both of these expressions are in the same fraction so all I'm doing is that if I choose zero for $x$ in $|f^3(x)|$ I must also plug in zero for $x$ in $|x-a|^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Hello? ?

Comment: The $n$-th Taylor's polynomial of $f$ centered at $a$ is $T_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}(x-a)^k$. Therefore $T_n(a)=f(a)$. The theorem says that for any $d>0$ and for all $x\in [a-d,a+d]$, $$\lvert f(x)-T_n(x)\rvert\le \frac1{(n+1)!}\lvert x-a\rvert^{n+1}\sup\limits_{t\in [a-d,a+d]}\lvert f^{(n+1)}(t)\rvert$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

By Taylor's theorem, the error is given by
$$
E = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(1/2)}{n!} (x-1/2)^n
  = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-1/2)^3,
$$
where $a \in (0,1/2)$. According to your claim, you can bound
$$
f^{(n)}(a) \le \frac{66}{125}.
$$
Can you now finish?

Comment: In the picture I posted above of Taylors Inequality, can you point out where I did something wrong